# MyBatis, Spring 3 and Transactions

Tags: java, spring, transactions, aop, mybatis

I am using:

spring: 3.1.0.M1
mybatis: 3.0.6
mybatis-spring: 1.0.2

I am trying to configure transactions at the Service layer which has DOA's underneath (using mybatis mappers). Something is wrong with the configuration as it is not working as I would expect - when the service layer uses  a number of mappers and fails the mappers before the fail have committed to the DB (not rolled back). This is my configuration:

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:repo/mybatis-config.xml"/>
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:com/xxx/repository/mappers/*.xml"/>
</bean>    
<bean id="customerMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.xxx.repository.mappers.CustomerMapper"/>
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"/>
</bean>
... other mappers ...

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>



<!-- Transaction Management -->
<tx:advice id="serviceAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="SUPPORTS" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="is*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="get*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="exists*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true"/> 
        <tx:method name="create*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false"/>
        <tx:method name="delete*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false"/>
        <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="servicePointcut" expression="execution(* com.xxx.service.*Service.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="servicePointcut" advice-ref="serviceAdvice"/>   
</aop:config>
```

What am I missing here?

Have updated Spring to RC2 and changed from using cp3o to BoneCP:

```
<!-- BoneCP configuration -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
   <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
   <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname" />
   <property name="username" value="username"/>
   <property name="password" value="password"/>
   <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60"/>
   <property name="idleMaxAge" value="240"/>
   <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="30"/>
   <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="10"/>
   <property name="partitionCount" value="3"/>
   <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5"/>
   <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="100"/>
   <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="3"/>
</bean>
```

But I am still getting the same issue.

Doh!

No, it works as expected! It's my brain that doesn't. I had an incorrect servicePointcut path...

Comment: BTW: Spring 3.1.0.RC2 is out, I recommend to update

Comment: What is the declaration of your datasource bean? Do you turn autocommit off? I'm assuming it's based on a DBCP pool, be good to verify that.